# Keeping slide-out div flush with left side of window upon window resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window, positioning

I have a slide-out div, absolutely positioned in a relatively positioned parent,  which moves nearly off the left side of the screen upon the click of a button.

I'm `animate()` -ing the css `left` property to move it. It looks fine until you resize the window. Upon resize, the div is then either too far into the page or too far outside of the page (depending on if you are enlarging or shrinking the window).

**How can I keep the div flush with the page upon resize?**

Basically I want the right side of the div to always be 15px from the window border when the div is "slid out".

I was able to replicate the problem on Codepen, but not jsFiddle:

http://cdpn.io/hjnHz

Click the "<" sign on the top right of the slideout div to slide it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) { if ($("#slideout").css('left') != '0px') $("#slideout").css('left', -($("#slideout").width() - 15)); });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/full/rjaHD